# a ≡ b mod p implies that $(\frac {a}{p}) =(\frac {b}{p})$ The Legendre Symbol

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, primitive-roots, legendre-symbol

**Prove**
$$a\equiv b\pmod p \Rightarrow (\frac {a}{p}) =(\frac {b}{p})$$

What I thought:

Let $g$ be a primitive root mod $p$. Then $(\frac {g^k}{p})=(-1)^k$. What should I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Way overcomplicated. If $k^2 \equiv a \mod p$ then $k^2 \equiv b \mod p$. That's all you need.

Comment: Thank you, woudn't that mean that both a and b are quadratic residues? So it would always be 1?

Comment: @HeavyWeight Please interpret my answer as a hint and try to work it out from there.